# Dynamics CRM/365 - Plugin for Recalculate Opportunity?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Is it possible to trigger a plugin upon clicking Recalculate Opportunity?

I registered a plugin for the Recalculate message but nothing is triggered as far as I can tell from the Plug-In Trace Log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot catch this event. Dynamics (Microsoft) did not opened/ added any method to catch this trigger. This happens all in background.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there's a way possible through Javascript?